# Shared Preferences - how long do they exist and can user edit them?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Shared Preferences - how long do they exist and can user edit them? I am going to store username in there, and I don't want for users to be able to edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how long do they exist

Until the app is uninstalled or the user presses the "Clear Data" button for the app in Settings.

> I don't want for users to be able to edit that

Normal users cannot get to the file. Rooted device users can get to whatever files that they want.

Comment: Okay, that means I can't store sensitive data like username which identifies which user is logged in, I have to store a unique random and long string for each user.

Comment: @good_evening: "I have to store a unique random and long string for each user" -- rooted device users can get to whatever files that they want. Either do not worry about rooted device users or do not store anything on the device.

Comment: That's not a problem, rooted users will not know other users that unique and random string.

Answer (score 0):

It exists for as long as your app is installed and is only accessible from code. So users will only be able to edit them if you allow them to.